# Extract individual values from a string in PHP

Tags: php, extract

I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'rgb(178, 114, 113)';
```

and I want to extract the individual values of that

```
$red = 178;
$green = 114;
$blue = 113;
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
preg_match_all('(\d+)', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 178
            [1] => 114
            [2] => 113
        )
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If your string will always start with `rgb(` and end with `)`, then you can [truncate the string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to just `178, 114, 113` with

```
$rgb = substr($string, 4, -1); //4 is the starting index, -1 means second to last character
```

Then to [convert the list to an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$vals = explode(', ', $rgb);
//or you could use just ',' and trim later if your string might be in the format `123,123, 123` (i.e. unknown where spaces would be)
```

At this point, `$vals[0]` is red, `$vals[1]` is green, and `$vals[2]` is blue.

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_match_all and list, you can get the variables you want:

```
$string = "rgb(178, 114, 113)";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $string, $matches);
list($red,$green,$blue) = $matches[0];
```

Please note that this doesn't validate that the original string does in fact have three integer values.